# Why can't I get `pip install lxml` to work within a virtualenv on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, pip, lxml, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

It keeps freezing or gives me the

**'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc': error.**

Comment: try this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/68907

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have tried the given solution still stuck in same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to just use the packaged versions of the `lxml` module.

If you're on Python 3:

```
apt-get install python3-lxml
```

Or on Python 2:

```
apt-get install python-lxml
```

If you create your virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`, you will have access to this install of `lxml` from the virtualenv.

I'm running Raspbian Stretch on my Pi, and it looks like `pip install` grabs a binary build (so no gcc required):

```
(venv) pi@lbb:~ $ pip install lxml
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting lxml
ww  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/lxml/lxml-4.2.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl (4.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.9MB 1.0MB/s 
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.2.1
```

Are you running the same distribution on your Pi? If not, please update your question to include that information.

Comment: Thanks, using --system-site-packages solved the problem , i had installed all the libraries but was not able to import in env.